# Match any character after a dot until either next dot or end of line

Tags: javascript, regex

As my question I want to match `foo` out of `asa .foo. assas` and in case of `bar .foo`.

While I know how to do one of these ending conditions, I don't know how to combine them.

My current work looks something like this:

```
/\.(.+?)(?=[\.|\Z])/g
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean *any* character (including whitespace)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
\.(\S*)(?=\.|$)
```

How it works:

```
\.    # . (Dot)
(     # Capture Data (foo)
  \S    # Any Non-Whitespace Character
  *     # 0 or more times
)
(?=   # Lookahead (Check) for...
  \.    # . (Dot)
  |     # OR
  $     # End of String
)
```

The data you want is stored in the **`1st` Capture Group**

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/gT4wT9/1)</kbd>

You may want to change it to this:

.(\S+?)(?=.|$)

Read **@РоманПарадеев**'s comment

---

**Problems with your RegEx:**

```
\.(.+?)(?=[\.|\Z])
```

- The `\.` is fine
- `.+?` **makes no sense** (actually, refer to **@РоманПарадеев**'s comment, you should probably use it).

  - `+` means **1** *or more* times, whereas `*` means **0** *or more* times. So I can see what you were trying to get at, but it is simpler to just use `(.*)` (unless there are multiple `.` in the string, and you want it to be non-greedy. Again, refer to **@РоманПарадеев**'s comment)
- `[\.|\Z]` will not work as you expected.

  - First, no need to escape the `\.`, just use `.`. Next, any character inside `[]` will be matched. This means it will match `.`, `|` or `\Z`. You only use `|` when inside a Group, like `\.|\Z`. Finally, you can use `$` instead of `\Z`
  - This means can `(?=\.|$)` **or** `(?=[.\Z])` (`\Z` needs to be used here because `$` matches a `$` literally)

Comment: Actually, `.+?` make a sense: a question mark makes a quantifier non-greedy, so it would match the fewest possible characters. That's why yout solution whould not handle strings with more than two dots, like `'a.b.c.d'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture next non-dot text after first DOT:

```
/^[^.]*\.([^.]*)/
```

Your text is available in captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI9rF9/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^          # line start
[^.]*      # match 0 or more chars that are not DOT
\.         # match a literal DOT
([^.]*)    # match 0 or more chars that are not DOT and capture the text in group #1
```

**Code:**

```js
    var re = /^[^.]*\.([^.]*)/gm; 
    var str = 'asa .foo. assas\nbar .foo';
    var m;
    var matches = [];

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
            re.lastIndex++;
        matches.push(m[1]);
    }

    document.writeln(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this: `/\.(\S+?)(?=\.|$)/g`

`\.` literal dot
`(\S+?)` one or more non-whitespace characters (non-greedy)
`(?=\.|$)` positive lookahead for either a dot or end-of-line

https://regex101.com/r/vL7cZ1/1

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should do:

```
\.(\w+)(?:\.\s+\S+)?$
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC1lI1/3)

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate against regexes in this case.

It can be done in a little bit more readable way.

```
'asa .foo. assas'.split('.')[1]
```